# Como cargar una grafica cuando le doy clic a una barra de otra grafica en chartjs

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

Tengo una duda, tengo una grafica principal en el cual muestro algunos valores.

Mi pregunta o mi duda es, en dicha grafica al momento de seleccionar algún valor quiero que se me cargue otra grafica referenciada al valor al cual le di clic.

¿Es esto posible o no se puede?

Saludos.

```js
var barChartData = {
  labels: ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio"],

  datasets: [{

      fillColor: "#6b9dfa",
      strokeColor: "#ffffff",
      highlightFill: "#1864f2",
      highlightStroke: "#ffffff",
      data: [90, 30, 10, 80, 15, 5, 15]

    },
    {

      fillColor: "#e9e225",
      strokeColor: "#ffffff",
      highlightFill: "#ee7f49",
      highlightStroke: "#ffffff",
      data: [40, 50, 70, 40, 85, 55, 15]

    }

  ]

}
var ctx3 = document.getElementById("chart-rea3").getContext("2d");
window.myPie = new Chart(ctx3).Bar(barChartData, {
  responsive: true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.1/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart-rea3" class="pie"></canvas>
```

Ejemplo, si doy clic en "Marzo", en otra grafica se carguen datos de la semana del mes seleccionado:

```js
var barChartData = {
  labels: ["1er semana", "2da semana", "3er semana", "4ta semana"],

  datasets: [{

      fillColor: "#6b9dfa",
      strokeColor: "#ffffff",
      highlightFill: "#1864f2",
      highlightStroke: "#ffffff",
      data: [90, 30, 10, 80]

    },
    {

      fillColor: "#e9e225",
      strokeColor: "#ffffff",
      highlightFill: "#ee7f49",
      highlightStroke: "#ffffff",
      data: [40, 50, 70, 40]

    }

  ]

}
var ctx3 = document.getElementById("chart-rea4").getContext("2d");
window.myPie = new Chart(ctx3).Bar(barChartData, {
  responsive: true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.1/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart-rea4" class="pie"></canvas>
```

Eso es lo que estoy buscando hacer con las graficas cargadas desde SQL y desde el backend con ASP.NET C#.

Comment: Si, es posible, ¿Qué haz intentado hacer?... adjunta el código que tienes hecho.

Comment: Ya adjunte el código de ejemplo sobre lo que quiero lograr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vayamos por partes

1.- La versión que estas usando es demasiado vieja, tienes que actualizarte

2.- Una manera es tener todos los datos a mano en una estructura similar a esta:

```
const DATOS =[
   {mes: "Enero",   semanas : [90,23,34,23]},
   {mes: "Febrero", semanas : [20,22,32,44]},
   {mes: "Marzo" ,  semanas : [50,53,34,21]},
   {mes: "Abril",   semanas : [60,77,44,88]},
];
```

*Otra opción es ir a buscar los datos con ajax*

3.- Luego asignamos el evento `onClick` en las opciones del chart principal, y obtenemos el índice clickeado, de esta manera

```
onClick: function(event, elements, chart){
  if(elements[0]){
     graficar(elements[0].index);
  }
}
```

4.- El evento `onClick` llamará a una función que mostrará el segundo gráfico

5.- Importante es destruirlo previamente (por si ha sido generado anteriormente), con la función `destroy()`

**Demo:**

*Hacer scroll, el segundo chart se encuentra abajo*

```js
const colors = [
      'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
      'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
      'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
      'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
      'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
      'rgba(201, 203, 207, 0.2)'
    ];
const DATOS =[
   {mes: "Enero",   semanas : [90,23,34,23]},
   {mes: "Febrero", semanas : [20,22,32,44]},
   {mes: "Marzo" ,  semanas : [50,53,34,21]},
   {mes: "Abril",   semanas : [60,77,44,88]},
];

  const ctx = document.getElementById('Chart1');

  new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels:  DATOS.map(a=>a.mes),
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Meses',
        data: DATOS.map(d=>d.semanas.reduce((a,i)=>a+i)),
        backgroundColor: colors,
      }]
    },
    options: {
      onClick: function(event, elements, chart){
        if(elements[0]){
          graficar(elements[0].index);
        }
      }
    }
  });

let chart2;
function graficar(index){
  const ctx = document.getElementById('Chart2');
  const datos2 = DATOS[index];
  
  const labels = Array.from({length: datos2.semanas.length}, (v, i) => "Semana " + i);
  
  if(chart2) chart2.destroy();
  
  chart2 = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels:  labels,
      datasets: [{
        label: datos2.mes,
        data: datos2.semanas,
        backgroundColor: colors[index],
      }]
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@4.3.2/dist/chart.umd.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="Chart1" class="pie"></canvas>
<canvas id="Chart2" class="pie"></canvas>
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, tendré en cuenta el actualizarme.