# Porque sale un espacio en blanco al lado derecho de la pagina? como elimino ese espacio?

Tags: css, scss, css-grid-layout, selectores-css

Estos practicando CSS con paginas responsivas pero me sale ese espacion en la resolucion de 1440px como hago apra eliminarlo ?

[image: pepito]

**mi css**

```
    .pagina {
  background-color: #2a2c2f;
  max-width: 1440px;
  margin: auto;
  font-family: "Inter";
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -moz-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0%;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

no se si estoy fallando en algo de mi css alqui dejo algo de mi codigo espero de sea ayuda no se si algo abre puesto mal si alguien le ha pasado algo parecido o saque como solucionarlo ?

Comment: Debes colocar un [MRE], para esto edita tu pregunta y presiona el botón cuyo icono es `<>` ahí te indicará que debes ingresar HTML+CSS+JS, tu ingresa el tuyo donde corresponda

Comment: en mi pregunta que le hace falta para que sea aceptada ?

Comment: Con los datos (código) que has puesto no es posible reproducir el problema. Si tu código no es muy grande ponlo todo, si ya es largo creas que un [MRE] que muestre tu el problema en cuestión.  Fíjate en esta pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/600511/301324 Mira que está todo el código necesario para reproducir el problema, y es más, es posible presionar el botón ejecutar y examinar directamente el funcionamiento sin herramientas adicionales.

Comment: A la `pagina` ponle un ancho de 100%, en la resolución de 1440px. Prueba con eso

Comment: ya lo solucione al parecer era un elemento que tenia un ancho que sobrepasaba el ancho del contenedor